# Netty FrameDecoder instance state

Tags: netty

In my Netty code I am writing a FrameDecoder to handle LDAP PDUs.  I have the code that allows me to determine if the PDU is complete (state is `PDU_DECODED`) or if more data is needed (`VALUE_STATE_PENDING`).  Plus there are a few more error conditions I can detect as well.

For most of the time I think that one read will get the whole PDU.  But for those times when I need another read to get more data, I want to know the best way to code it.

Now in my `decode()` I am marking the reader index, `buf.markReaderInded()`, reading in the bytes available, do a check on the bytes read to see if it is a valid PDU.  If it is, I return the bytes read.  If it isn't, then I reset the reader index, `buf.resetReaderIndex()`, and return null.  The next time I come back into `decode()` I will have the original data plus data from the next read.   I can run the check again.

But I would like to store the original data read in the first time and on the next read get the rest of the PDU (or next part).  I would then add that data to what I already have stored in the instance of my framedecoder and check if it is a valid PDU.  This time I wouldn't have done a reset on the reader index, `buf.resetReaderIndex()`, but just returned a  null.

By the way, I am already using the`setAttachment()`/`getAttachment()` to store information in the `ChannelHandlerContext`.  So I can't use that.  I set it when I get a connection.

I am not sure what state I am in when I come back into decode() once again.  Is it the same instance or a new instance of my `FrameDecoder` class?  Would I have the variables defined and set before available to me?  I am not sure what Netty does here.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need the Netty [ReplayingDecoder](http://static.netty.io/3.6/api/org/jboss/netty/handler/codec/replay/ReplayingDecoder.html). You basically define your decoding steps, or checkpoints, as members in an **enum**. You start reading on the first call for an object and as soon as you over-read the buffer, netty automatically "waits" for more incoming data and replays when it gets some. Once you reach a known checkpoint, you transition the decoder to the next state. When netty calls the decoder, it passes the last known state, so you always know where you are. It's great for handling complex objects, and/or where you have conditional branches within the decode. There's a good tutorial [here](http://biasedbit.com/netty-tutorial-replaying-decoder/).

Comment: I looked at the ReplayingDecoder, but I didn't think it was what I needed.  I am reading in all the bytes available to me and working with those.  I evaluate what I just read, if it is a complete PDU then I return what I have.  If not then I return a null and the next time back I add the new bytes and evaluate again.  If I got an error then I throw an exception.

Comment: A ReplayingDecoder implementation will answer your question "I am not sure what state I am in when I come back into decode() once again".

Comment: Ok, I see that it will allow me to keep the state information on my processing handy and with less fuss.  Thank you for help.